# python function call not printing as expected

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, function-call

So I have 2 functions - displayHand(hand) and calculateHandlen(hand)

```
def displayHand(hand):
    """
    Displays the letters currently in the hand.

    For example:
    >>> displayHand({'a':1, 'x':2, 'l':3, 'e':1})
    Should print out something like:
       a x x l l l e
    The order of the letters is unimportant.

    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    """
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for j in range(hand[letter]):
             print(letter,end=" ")       
    print() 

def calculateHandlen(hand):
    """ 
    Returns the length (number of letters) in the current hand.

    hand: dictionary (string-> int)
    returns: integer
    """
    handLen = 0
    for i in hand:
        handLen = handLen + hand.get(i,0)

    return handLen
```

There's a loop in another function that is dependent on the above functions -

```
def playHand(hand, wordList, n): 
"""
   hand = dictionary 
   wordList = list of valid words
   n = an integer passed while function call  
"""
    totalscore = 0
    while(calculateHandlen(hand)>0):
        print("Current Hand: " +str(displayHand(hand)))

        newWord = input('Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished: ')
```

Function call for playHand() is as follows:

```
wordList = loadWords() #loadWords could be a list of words
playHand({'n':1, 'e':1, 't':1, 'a':1, 'r':1, 'i':2}, wordList, 7)
```

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
Current Hand: n e t a r i i 
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:
```

However, it displays the following:

```
n e t a r i i   
Current Hand: None  
Enter word, or a "." to indicate that you are finished:
```

Don't know where I'm going wrong.

Note: I'm not allowed to make any changes to the first 2 functions.

Comment: `displayHand()` returns `None`, and prints itself. Don't use `print()` but return your value, if you want to pass it back to the caller.

Comment: I'm not allowed to make changes to displayHand(). Any changes are supposed to be in playHand().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`displayHand()` doesn't return anything, so the default `None` is returned. When you call it, it prints the output directly.

If you are not allowed to alter `displayHand()`, you need to print your label *first*, then call the function:

```
print("Current Hand: ", end='')
displayHand(hand)
```

The `end=''` removes the newline `print()` would normally write.